# Can't remove .php from website using htaccess. Dreamhost server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, dreamhost

I am trying to remove the ".php" on my website. I have changed the .htaccess file based on the documentation provided in the dreamhost wiki to the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

However, this does not work on the site. For example this code does not work:

```
<a href ="about">link</a>
```

It shows the following error:

Not Found

The requested URL /jimmyvosler.com/public/about.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This works (but still displays the .php at the end, which is what im trying to fix):

```
<a href ="about.php">link</a>
```

I don't understand what is causing this, especially since the error even points to the correct place. Is there a setting I need to check on my admin tool?

Comment: What is the full path to the second link `about.php`? The fact that the server gives you a 404, makes me think the reroute location is incorrect. If the removal of the extension failed I'm pretty sure you'd get something more along the lines of a 500 or 503 (server errors) rather than a 404 (client error)...

Comment: you could solve this issue by placing about.php in a directory named "about" and renaming it to "index.php". change any links to link to the directory and they wont see the .php. This is pretty standard practice and keeps you from having to mess around with htaccess.

Comment: Change `/$1.php` to `$1.php`

Comment: I've tried changing the /$1.php to #1.php but this didn't seem to do anything. Bradley is right though, I tried the folder index trick and that worked. That seems like such a hassle though. I think I'm going to spend some more time trying to figure out how to do it with htaccess before resorting to the folder trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for anyone else that has the same trouble. I added this to my .htaccess file. This solution came from dreamhost support and was linked from this website:  http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```